# Rxjs with Angular 1.5

Tags: rxjs, angularjs

I Would like to add `Rxjs` to my project which is based on `Angular 1.5`. I install `Rxjs` by `npm i -D rxjs`, add to my `index.html` like this

`<script src="../node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js"></script>`

Also added `rx` to my `app.module.js` file.

Console returned me

> Rx.ts:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at Rx.ts:5

Where it could be a problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use one of the UMD bundles in the `node_modules/rxjs/bundles` directory. For example:

```
<script src="../node_modules/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
```

Which contains the unminified source.

The file you have used - `node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js` - is a CommonJS module, hence the error you received regarding `require` not being defined. CommonJS modules are not directly usable in `script` elements.